# Centering Nav Bar with Dropdown

Tags: html, css

I am having problems centering my navigation bar with a dropdown menu. I want to center the bar, and the dropdown underneath it. I have tried to use a regular unordered list, and now a table to center the dropdown part. I have seen examples of code working, but when I implement it into my nav bar it does not work with the dropdown. I am wanting to have the nav bar be a fluid width, not a set width, as I can get a set width to kind of work. Any help?
HTML:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

#navbar {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#navbar li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
#navbar li ul {
  display: none;
}
#navbar li:hover ul,
#navbar li.hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  left: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar li:hover li,
#navbar li.hover li {
  float: center;
}
#navbar li:hover li a,
#navbar li.hover li a {
  color: #999;
}
#navbar li li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <table width="275" border="5" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><a href="#">Spraying</a>
          </td>
          <td align="right"><a href="#">Combining</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><a href="#">Planting</a>
          </td>
          <td align="right"><a href="#">Drilling</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><a href="#">Strip Tillage</a>
          </td>
          <td align="right"><a href="#">Tillage</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Packages</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to center the bar, and the dropdown underneath it.

Then, you have to remove the `left` property on the `#navbar`. Otherwise, it is good.

You put the dropdown ul in `absolute` position with a `100% width`.

> I am wanting to have the nav bar be a fluid width, not a set width, as
>   I can get a set width to kind of work.

Also, it is `:hover` state. `.hover` means the class "hover".

[See this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/8tphdeor/7/)

Comment: I have looked at it and it does not look like it centers the main nav bar.

Comment: I know what you means. Then you don't have to put a fluid width of it, just `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center` on the `body` parent. Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/8tphdeor/7/

Comment: That is looking better, but now I want to add padding between the words, but just adding 5px to the padding: doesn't seem to work. I also want the dropdown table to be centered under services. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8tphdeor/8/ You can play with margin-left to center it under services with relative position on `li` Padding is working on `a` when I increase it, you can see.
Put the subject as resolved if it's ok for you :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. That did it for me.

Comment: you're welcome, glad it helps. Put the subject as solved if it's ok for you :)